# Parse text file and store delimited fields in hash table (Perl)

Tags: perl, file, parsing, hash, hashmap

I'm fairly new to Perl, so apologies if I'm missing something very simple here.

I have a file formatted like so:

```
TGName: name1             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3   
 setting4                                          value4
 setting5                                          value5

 ...
 ...

TGName: name47             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3

 ...
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SGName: name1             
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 ...
```

which needs to be compared to a similar text file (that is formatted *out of order*). My thinking was I could store each "block" of the textfile in a hash, so the above would look like:

```
my %TGName:name1= (
    setting1 => 'value1',
    setting2 => 'value2',
    setting3 => 'value3',
    setting4 => 'value4',
);
```

and so on, and then I could compare each hash with the same name in both files against each other.

The problem I'm facing right now is reading each line that starts with TGName, SGName, etc. into the hash with the settings and values as the key/value pairs.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14649523/perl-reading-a-file-and-storing-each-line-as-variable-value?answertab=active#tab-top) question's edit is the closest to what I've found while searching, but unfortunately no one answered after the original question was edited.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Here's some code for a somewhat similar (and simpler) project where every single line was unique and not separated into groups. Here, the output listed lines common to both files, lines only found in the first file, and lines only found in the second file:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Compare;

# create log.txt for writing
my $log = 'log.txt';

# create $f1 string and read in file1
open (my $f1, "<", "file1.txt") or die $!;

# create $f2 string and read in file2
open (my $f2, "<", "file2.txt") or die $!;

# initialize array and populate with the contents of $f1
my @content_f1=<$f1>;

# initialize array and populate with the contents of $f2
my @content_f2=<$f2>;

# create comparison string
my $lc = List::Compare->new(\@content_f1, \@content_f2);    

# initialize array showing commonalities of file 1 and file 2  
# and populate with the contents of get_intersection() 
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;

# initialize array showing elements unique to new config  
# and populate with the contents of get_unique() 
my @firstonly = $lc->get_unique;

# initialize array showing elements unique to golden config
# and populate with the contents of get_complement() 
my @secondonly = $lc->get_complement;

# create $out string to write contents into log
open(my $out, '>', $log) or die "Cannot open file '$log' for writing: $!";

# write the contents of the intersection and unique arrays to log.txt
print $out "Common Items:\n"."@intersection"."\n";
print $out "Items Only in file 1 \n"."@firstonly"."\n";
print $out "Items Only in file 2:\n"."@secondonly"."\n";

close $out;
close $f1;
close $f2;
```

Ideally I'd like the same kind of output here, except instead of comparing text file to text file, it's comparing %file1_hash_name1 to %file2_hash_name1(eg: items common to both hashes, items found in only the first hash, items found in only the second hash).

Comment: *"needs to be compared to a similar text file"* Okay, but what result do you want exactly? Just a list of records that are in one file but not the other? If the order matters then remember that hashes are *unordered*. How big are your files?

Comment: Edited in some previous code I used for clarity; hopefully that helps. Files are ~20,000 lines of text. If hashes are unordered, is there a better way to store them for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, I am using the **eq_deeply** function from [Test::Deep](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::Deep) to test for equality between your 2 files.

If you are also looking for what is in one file that is not in the other, you could use the List::Compare functions as you have them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::Deep::NoTest 'eq_deeply';
use List::Compare;

open my $fh, '<', \<<EOF;
TGName: name1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3   
 setting4                                          value4
 setting5                                          value5


TGName: name47
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SGName: name1
EOF

my %data1;
my $key1;

while (<$fh>) {
    if (/^([A-Z]{2}Name: name\d+)/) {
        $key1 = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^[-\s]+$/) {
        next;
    }
    else {
        my ($setting, $val) = split;    
        $data1{$key1}{$setting} = $val;
    }
}

open my $fh2, '<', \<<EOF;
TGName: name1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3   
 setting4                                          value4
 setting55                                          value5


TGName: name47
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting1                                          value1 
 setting2                                          value2
 setting3                                          value3

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
SGName: name11
EOF

my %data2;
my $key2;

while (<$fh2>) {
    if (/^([A-Z]{2}Name: name\d+)/) {
        $key2 = $1;
    }
    elsif (/^(?:-+|\s+)$/) {
        next;
    }
    else {
        my ($setting, $val) = split;    
        $data2{$key2}{$setting} = $val;
    }
}

my $lc = List::Compare->new([keys %data1], [keys %data2]);
my @intersection = $lc->get_intersection;

for my $key (@intersection) {
    if (eq_deeply($data1{$key}, $data2{$key})) {
        print "key $key has the same hash for both files\n";    
    }
    else {
        print "key $key has different hashes\n";    
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
key TGName: name1 has different hashes
key TGName: name47 has the same hash for both files
```

I haven't used the **eq_deeply** function myself, but I believe it will give you the results you need.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was more looking for the output to be a comparison of the contents and their differences against each other, but the way you parsed the text and stored it in the hash was exactly what I was stuck on.

Comment: @Sameer: *"I was more looking for the output to be a comparison of the contents and their differences against each other"* It would have helped enormously if you had said so in your question. Even after I asked ***"what result do you want exactly?"*** you offered only some old code.